# ContextMenuStrip, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Сделал меню правой кнопки мыши для `Datagridview`. Но не могу понять, запустил приложение, кликаю 1 раз, меню не появляется, кликнул второй раз - появилось и дальше уже норм работает, закрою, открою форму снова, такая же проблема, первый раз кликну не откроется потом норм работает. Что я не так делаю?

```
        private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            try
            {
                ContextMenuStrip shift_my_menu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
                int position_x_y_mouse = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
                if (position_x_y_mouse >= 0)
                {
                    shift_my_menu.Items.Add("Редактировать").Name = "edit";
                    shift_my_menu.Items.Add("Удалить").Name = "del";
                }
                shift_my_menu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                shift_my_menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(shift_my_menu_ItemClicked);
                shift_my_menu.Items["del"].Image = MSU.Properties.Resources.delete;
                shift_my_menu.Items["edit"].Image = MSU.Properties.Resources.edit;
```

Comment: Окно активно в момент первого клика? Может быть окно не активно и вы первым кликом делаете окно активным, а лишь потом вс енормально работает.

Comment: Не стоит создавать контекстное меню каждый раз при клике мышкой. Лучше его создать один раз и дальше использовать. При необходимости скрывая/показывая отдельные пункты меню (см. свойство `Visible` у них).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, пробовал и так и так, с первого раза меню не открывает, фокус при этом на `datagridview`, таким же методом вызываю меню в главном окне, там такой проблемы нету. Может ли это быть связано с тем что окно дополнительное?

Comment: @iluxa1810 при вызове меню `datagridview` при этом активен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, перепробовал все что знал, не помогает, прошу Вас подскажите мне что же все таки не так? Метод создания меню одинаковый на основной форме и на второстипенный, на основной все отлично работает, на всех второстпинных вызывает только после второго клика и дальше работает нормально до перезапуска формы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, сейчас использую костыль, вот это - `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                sub_my_menu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }` повесил и на `mouse_down` и `mouse_click` тогда открывает с 1 раза.